# Calling an object method using a function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am playing around tkinter, and I was wondering if I had declared a method within an object, can I call it using the 'protocol' method of tkinter? or any function to be exact ie.

```
class Notepad():
    ...
    ...
    def exit_func():
        #Messagebox command warning 'You are exiting'


root = tk.Tk()
notepad = Notepad(root)
root.geometry("800x500")

root.mainloop()

#Problem is here
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.exit_func())
```

I tried this with my program, where my 'exit_func' had a 'get' function from tkinter and i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Notepad_with_console.py", line 204, in <module>
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", notepad.exit_file())
File "Notepad_with_console.py", line 175, in exit_file
if self.text.get(1.0,tk.END) != '' and self.current_file_dir == '':
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3246, in get
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', index1, index2)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text"
```

Is there a reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: `app.exit_func()` is the *result of calling the function right now*, which is probably None.  `app.exit_func` is *the function itself*, which is what you'd want to pass to `.protocol()` to be called later.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root.protocol` requires a *reference* to a function. Instead, you're immediately calling a function and then passing in the result.

Consider this code:

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.exit_func())
```

That code is functionally identical to this:

```
result = app.exit_func()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", result)
```

Instead, you need to pass in a *reference* to the function:

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.exit_func)
```